# is there a environment variable for tomee-home that I can use in context.xml

Tags: apache-tomee

I've a webapp that is being deployed to a tomee server.  This webapp has a META-INF/context.xml file and its content is as of below:

```
<Context>
  <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader" virtualClasspath="/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/someProperties;" />
  <JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true" />
</Context>
```

Notice that the Loader element's  virtualClasspath attr has a value of /apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/someProperties;, where /apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2 is ready the tomcat home.  Do you know if there a way to refer to the tomcat-home without hard code the actual path name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can use ${catalina.home} to refer to tomcat-home directory.